# how to edit big images in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, zooming

I am trying to save small images from the original which I load from SDcard. Android doesn't allow me to create bitmap of bigger image sizes so I had to use **options**, doing so my images' resolution is altered so now how i am supposed to edit the original image??

And saving images, do I have the bitmap.compress option alone? If so, this reduces the quality of the image when i open and save it in **JPG**

And how can I display them independent of the screen???

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to display big image in Android by using BitmapRegionDecoder. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

Comment: Simple link giving is not an answer, you should also write something about it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer. One of the rules is to add context to links, instead of just pasting them. You should provide an answer that is valid without the need for the user to navigate to another side, but might wish to do so for more detail on the answer. That becomes a bigger problem when the links for some reason become invalid.